# Binding this to the event handler in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I just read book about react js for beginner, but i have a trouble. This is just simple problem in button element as you can see there is an event handler that i pass an argument. The handler  is useful for if we click the button then the element next to it will disappear. it works correctly if i just wrote this line

`<button onClick={ () => this.onDismiss(item.objectID) } type="button"> // using arrow function`

Because of performance issue i am looking for another way

The problem is how i can bind `this` to the `onDismiss` handler... i've tried bind this in constructor, but it doesn't help. Can you help me fix this or give me a suggestion?

````
constructor() {
    super();
    
    this.state = {
      list,
    };

    this.onDismiss = this.onDismiss.bind(this);

  }
 
  onDismiss(id) {
    const isNotId = (item) => item.objectID !== id;
    const updatedList = this.state.list.filter(isNotId);
    this.setState({list : updatedList});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.list.map( item => 
          <div key={item.objectID}> 
            <span>
              <button onClick={ function() {this.onDismiss(item.objectID)}} type="button">
                Dismiss
              </button>
            </span>
          </div>
          )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: What performance issues are you facing by using `() => this.onDismiss(item.objectID)`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that here:

```js
<button onClick={ function() {this.onDismiss(item.objectID)}} type="button">
    Dismiss
</button>
```

Your inline `function` is unbound, ending in `this` being undefined. Replace it with an arrow function, and it will work:

```js
<button onClick={() => this.onDismiss(item.objectID)} type="button">
    Dismiss
</button>
```